# Setting Default Values in HashMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to find a way to make a HashMap return a default value. For example if you look at the following this will printout "**Test:=null**" what if I want to request a default value so anytime I try to get something that is NOT set in the hashMap I will get the value?

```
Map<String, String> test = new HashMap<String, String>();
test.put("today","monday");
System.out.println("Test =:" + test.get("hello") + "");
```

Comment: Override the `Map`. Note this will break the contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better check the return value instead of changing the way a `Map` works IMO. The [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) `StringUtils.defaultString(String)` method should do the trick:

```
Map<String, String> test = new HashMap<>();
assertEquals("", StringUtils.defaultString(test.get("hello")));
assertEquals("DEFAULT", StringUtils.defaultString(test.get("hello"), "DEFAULT"));
```

StringUtils JavaDoc is [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).

Answer (score 8):

Try the following:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>(){
    @Override
    public String get(Object key) {
        if(! containsKey(key))
            return "DEFAULT";
        return super.get(key);
    }
};

System.out.println(map.get("someKey"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than try to give a value to the data, why don't you just do a check when you want to pull the data?

```
if (!set.containsKey(key)){
    return default_value;
}
else{
    return set.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use it as a switch condition.
You can override the get method by extending it into another class or you may try it as follows :

```
Map<String, String> test = new HashMap<String, String>();
test.put("today", "monday");
String s = test.get("hello") == null? "default value" : test.get("hello");
System.out.println("Test =:" + s);
```

or

```
    final String defaultValue = "default value";
    Map<String, String> test = new HashMap<String, String>() {

        @Override
        public String get(Object key) {
            String value = super.get(key);
            if (value == null) {
                return defaultValue;
            }
            return value;
        };
    };
    test.put("today", "monday");            
    System.out.println("Test =:" + test.get("nokey"));
```

And also you can achieve this by simply using `Properties` class instead of `HashMap`.

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("key1", "value of key1");
        String property1 = properties.getProperty("key1", "default value");
        String property2 = properties.getProperty("key2", "default value");
        System.out.println(property1);
        System.out.println(property2);
```

which prints :

```
value of key1
default value
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the `HashMap` and override the `get()`.