# Initialize a Map with new Lists in Java

Tags: java, maps, package

Can I build a Map more succinctly? Sort of like `Sets.cartesianProduct(set1, set2, ... )`, I'd like a one-liner to build a map with empty, initialized, mutable Lists. The following code is just for illustration.

```
Map<MyEnumeration, List<String>> answer = new HashMap<>();
for (MyEnumeration enum : MyEnumeration.values()) {
    answer.put(enum, new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

I like other people's [tested] code. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220835/setting-default-values-in-hashmap) isn't quite right, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626280/java-initialize-a-hashmap-of-hashmaps) is really about how to instantiate things and despite the title, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887598/initializing-a-map-with-list-inside) is really a question about generics.

Comment: Well, that would depend on how you're getting the list?

Comment: @RohitJain Right here, I want a new list, but if I had a collection of Lists, and I could do a cartesian product-like operation, that'd work.

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: @RohitJain Java 7 :(

Comment: Then there is no one-liner I'm afraid.

Comment: @RohitJain 'No' is a perfectly acceptable answer - I'll upvote and accept it if you list a few plausible packages (com.​google.​common.​collect.​Maps) etc... which don't contain this operation. Conversely, if it's possible in Java 8 but not 7, I'll upvote and accept if you outline that code as well.

Comment: The only alternative I can offer you is to create your own `Map` class by inheriting from `AbstractMap`. In there you can create a constructor that would take your enumeration and create the keys from it as well as generating the `List` objects for each key. As far as JDK goes, there is no `Map` implementation which does what you describe in your post.

Comment: @I.K. I thought about that, but it defeats the purpose of the one liner that's been tested by smarter people with more use-cases.

Comment: I would hardly say that *'been tested by smarter people...'* is the purpose of one-liners. But if you are looking for code in the JDK that does this, then, I repeat, you are out of luck. Unless like I said, you build your own custom Map class.

Comment: @I.K. Brevity (clarity) is also a purpose, but as I said, 'No, and here's why and what I checked'  is a perfectly acceptable answer which I will post if nobody else does. I appreciate the power of overriding methods, but a static factory would also suffice.

Comment: are you open to using the Guava library?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75318/discussion-between-user121330-and-i-k).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EnumMap`.

For example:

```
Map<MyEnumeration, List<String>> answer = new EnumMap(MyEnumeration.class);
```

Comment: The lists aren't initialized.

Comment: @user121330 even adding a empty list to map is fine , u can fill it up later

Comment: @SrinathGanesh that'd be identical in code lines to the code I offered.